# Can anyone please explain these iPhone logs to me?

Tags: ios, iphone, logging

Please help! Is this a trusted binary? Why is it dirtying memory? Is launchd [1] trusted? It mentions the SiriusXM APP at some point which I can post in comments if needed. Please not that this is not the entire log. If needed, please request and I can post the rest. Thank you so much in advance!

```
{"share_with_app_devs":0,"app_version":"","bug_type":"145","timestamp":"2021-05-26 00:12:08.00 -0400","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)","slice_uuid":"894FF538-0742-39A3-B694-0909336FAD08","is_first_party":1,"build_version":"","incident_id":"5CCEEB74-2F96-4567-84B1-3D521EBEDE53","app_name":"aggregated","name":"aggregated"}
Date/Time:        2021-05-25 07:32:33.316 -0400
End time:         2021-05-26 00:12:06.994 -0400
OS Version:       iPhone OS 14.6 (Build 18F72)
Architecture:     arm64e
Report Version:   32
Incident Identifier: 5CCEEB74-2F96-4567-84B1-3D521EBEDE53

Data Source:      Microstackshots
Shared Cache:     42E6D1CB-BF6C-359D-A3D8-AD0D179BC8B6 slid base address 0x1a6754000, slide 0x26754000

Command:          aggregated
Path:             /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/Support/aggregated
Version:          ??? (???)
Parent:           launchd [1]
PID:              77

Event:            disk writes
Action taken:     none
Writes:           1073.76 MB of file backed memory dirtied over 59974 seconds (17.90 KB per second average), exceeding limit of 12.43 KB per second over 86400 seconds
Writes limit:     1073.74 MB
Limit duration:   86400s
Writes caused:    1073.76 MB
Writes duration:  59974s
Duration:         59973.68s
Duration Sampled: 59970.98s
Steps:            2233 ( (10.49 MB/step))

Hardware model:   iPhone13,1
Active cpus:      6


Heaviest stack for the target process:
  52  ??? (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14244) [0x1f282e7a4]
  52  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 95420) [0x1a67b24bc]
  32  ??? (libxpc.dylib + 62592) [0x1f2855480]
  32  ??? (libxpc.dylib + 61628) [0x1f28550bc]
  16  ??? (aggregated + 20912) [0x100cd91b0]
  16  ??? (libxpc.dylib + 78904) [0x1f2859438]
  16  ??? (aggregated + 22332) [0x100cd973c]
  9   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 248556) [0x1aff25aec]

  9   ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 172284) [0x1d4de40fc]


Powerstats for:   aggregated [77]
UUID:             894FF538-0742-39A3-B694-0909336FAD08
Path:             /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/Support/aggregated
Architecture:     arm64e
Parent:           launchd [1]
UID:              501
Sudden Term:      Tracked
Footprint:        10.72 MB -> 12.02 MB (+1328 KB) (max 16.58 MB )
Pageins:          259 pages
Start time:       2021-05-25 07:58:02.115 -0400
End time:         2021-05-26 00:12:06.836 -0400
Num samples:      66 (3%)
Primary state:    49 samples Non-Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS Background, Requested Thread QoS Background, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
User Activity:    52 samples Idle, 14 samples Active
Power Source:     60 samples on Battery, 6 samples on AC
```